# How to use const in switch statement and another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a *switch statement* in which a variable **stage** changes if certain conditions are met. This variable has to be used outside the *switch* in another function. How could I use this globally in the same file?

```
const stage= 5

export default function (state = INIT, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.EXAMPLE:
             let stage = 0
             if (CONDITION) {
                 stage = 1
             }
             else{
                 stage = 2
             }
             return{ ...state, someState: someState, }

        default:
             return state      
    }
}
```

*switch* statement ends and a new function **exampleFunction** begins. 
I want to use **stage** here.

```
let exampleFunction = (data, exampleData) => {
   if (stage == 2) return generateSomething();}
   else { generateSomethingElse(); }

return data;
}
```

Comment: _"switch statement ends and a new function exampleFunction begins"_: it's not clear how. The first code is a reducer. Where does the other code fit in?

Comment: Andy, I've got _let exampleFunction_ straight after _export default function_ just found as it is.

Comment: "*a variable `stage` changes if certain conditions are met.*" - well then don't make it `const` if you plan to change it

Comment: All sorted. Thank you Andy for pointing out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, `stage` is entirely private to the default function you're exporting. If you want to use `stage` outside of that function, you need to include it in the return value, and then use that function where you want `stage`.

(Also note that `if (stage = 2)` is incorrect, `=` is for *assignment*. For comparison, use `==` or `===`.)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. What would be the best way to return stage.. as whenever I return it, it is still 5 - as if switch did not change it?

Comment: Why isn't it part of your app state?

Comment: If these two are in the same function, I get _exampleFunction_ used before it was defined error